# mysql return same rows union

Tags: php, mysql

In my database i have categories, offers and coupons. i would like to count offers and coupons that exist in each category. when i use union it returns the same category twice.
i have the below query that returning same category rows with same name. i try to use union distinct but it does not work.

```
(SELECT 
        cat1.id AS cat1id, cat1.title AS title,
        count(offers.id) AS offercounter

    FROM cat1

    INNER JOIN offers 
    ON offers.category=cat1.title

    GROUP BY cat1.id
    order by cat1.order)
     UNION
    (SELECT 
        cat1.id AS cat1id, cat1.title AS title,
        count(coupons.id) AS couponscounter

    FROM cat1

    INNER JOIN coupons 
    ON coupons.category=cat1.title

    GROUP BY cat1.id
    order by cat1.order)
```

the result

```
cat1id  title         offercounter
 2       Food              5388
 23      Clothes           6000(this is offers)
 32      Technology         499
 40      Clothes            4(this is coupons)
```

i would like clothes to be (offercounter + couponscounter). 
example: clothes=6004 and not two different rows

the desired result would be :

```
cat1id  title         offercounter
 2       Food              5388
 23      Clothes           6004(offers+coupons)
 32      Technology         499
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative avoiding unions or sub queries is to use a couple of LEFT OUTER JOINS, and count the distinct ids from each table:-

```
SELECT cat1.id AS cat1id, 
        cat1.title AS title,
        COUNT(DISTINCT offers.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT coupons.id) AS offercounter
FROM cat1
LEFT OUTER JOIN offers ON offers.category = cat1.title
LEFT OUTER JOIN coupons ON coupons.category = cat1.title
GROUP BY cat1.id AS cat1id, 
        cat1.title AS title
```

EDIT

A left outer join will return a row of nulls when there is no matching row.

For example if there was a row on cat1 with a matching row on offers but no matching row on coupons then the resulting row would consist of the row from cat1, the row from offers and the fields from coupons would be null.

This SQL will get every combination of matching rows. So if you had:-

```
cat1 fields     offers fields       coupons fields
id  title       id      category    id      category
1   fred        99      fred        77      fred
1   fred        99      fred        88      fred
1   fred        100     fred        77      fred
1   fred        100     fred        88      fred
2   burt        120     fred        NULL    NULL
2   burt        121     fred        NULL    NULL
```

Hence the count uses DISTINCT to only could each id within a category once. As COUNT(field name) only counts non null values, with this example data for the 2nd category the count from coupons will be 0.

Comment: thank you! it works perfectly! i tried to understand the left outer join in your code but i couldnt. can you explain me how the left outer join brings the same results as the inner?

Comment: I have tried to add a bit more of a description for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Union returns distinct rows. Your returned rows are distinct indeed. What you need to do to get your desired result is aggregate after unioning.

```
select min(cat1id) as cat1id, title, sum(offercounter) as offercounter
 from 
(your_query) as subquery
group by title
```

replace your_query with your existing query

Comment: One thing to note if doing this is to change your query (used as a sub query) to use UNION ALL. Otherwise there is a small chance that there will be an identical row from each table and one is eliminated as a duplicate rather than summing them both up.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple `sum` up the `offercounter` and use `group by` with `order by` `cat1id`.

```
SELECT cat1id,title,sum(offercounter) as offercounter 
FROM offers GROUP BY title ORDER BY cat1id
```

View : [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3f92/5)

Output :

```
cat1id   title            offercounter
 2       Food             5388
 23      Clothes          6004
 32      Technology       499
```

Comment: could you please explain me because i cant open sql fiddle

Comment: Select your the columns you need and `sum` up the `offercounter` column value, above query will return the same output you desired.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

```
SELECT cat1.id AS cat1id, cat1.title AS title ,((SELECT COUNT(offers.id) FROM offers WHERE offers.category=cat1.title)+(SELECT COUNT(coupons.id) FROM coupons WHERE coupons.category=cat1.title)) AS offercounter
FROM cat1
```